# Learning Curve Models and the lspline package in R, Set a flat slope?

Tags: r, spline

I am working on a learning curve model of operating room time. The literature suggests using a "line-plateau" model. The theory is as a surgeon repeats a surgery, they improve rapidly until they reach a plateau and stop improving on that surgery. I used lspline to model the two time periods, but the problem I have is that in the second period the slope is positive (the surgery is taking longer). Does anyone know how to model a linear spline regression in r with one knot and force the second period to be flat, i.e. just an intercept?

```
    library(lspline)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    #Simulated Data
    set.seed(321)
    df1 <- data.frame(Case = seq(1,90,by=1), random = rnorm(90,0,1))
    df1$ORTime<-144-0.3*df1$Case+df1$random
    df2 <- data.frame(Case = seq(91,150,by=1), random = rnorm(60,0,1))
    df2$ORTime<-112+0.05*df2$Case+df2$random
    simulateddata<-rbind(df1,df2)
    
    #Spline Regression
    splinepredict<-predict(lm(ORTime~lspline(Case,90), 
                          data = simulateddata))
    summary(lm(ORTime~lspline(Case,90), 
           data = simulateddata))
    
    #Plot the Regression
    OrTime <- ggplot(simulateddata, aes(x=Case, y=ORTime)) +
      geom_point(alpha=0.55, color="black") + 
      theme_minimal()
    
    OrTime + 
      geom_line(data=simulateddata, 
                aes(y = splinepredict, x=Case), size = 1, col="blue")
```

[image: Plot of Learning Curve with Datapoints]